# Prove $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-x^{2n}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ point convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-x^{2n}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ point convergence

My proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$,and $N=\left[\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{ln(2x)}\right]+1$ if $x\in[a,\infty)$ and $n\geq N$, then

$|f_{n}(x)-0|=|x^{n}-x^{2n}|\leq|x^{N}-x^{2N}|\leq2x^{N}=2x^{\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{ln(2x)}+1}<\epsilon$

Comment: How do you know that $|x^{n}-x^{2n}|\leq|x^{N}-x^{2N}|?$ And that $2x^{\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{ln(2x)}+1}<\epsilon?$

Comment: How do we know that $$2x^{\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2x)}+1}<\epsilon\ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in[0,1]$

> - if $\;x=0$

$\forall n\geq0 \;\; f_n(0)=0\implies\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=0$

> - if$ \;x=1$

$\forall n\geq0\;\; f_n(1)=0\implies\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(1)=0$

> - if$\;\;0<x<1$

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0-0=0$

this proves that the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)_n$ at $[0,1]$ is zero function.

Answer (score 1):

if $x=1$ then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$. Otherwise, $0\le x\lt1$  and we have:
$$
|x^n-x^{2n}| = x^n(1-x^n)\le x^n \xrightarrow{ n\rightarrow\infty }0
$$
Also, note that $f_n\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}$, so that the convergence is only pointwise, and not uniform.